# Learning about geometric bezier splines

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I want to understand geometric Bezier splines. I have basically no advanced maths but am willing to learn. Can anybody suggest a good starting point for a *complete* beginner to start learning what I need to know to understand how splines are constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [these on-line notes](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/notes.html).

I agree that Farin's book is very good.

A more elementary one is [this one by Mortenson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0831132981).

Answer (score 1):

A very good book on the subject is *Curves and Surfaces for CAGD - A Practical Guide* by Gerald Farin. The presentation is very instructive and requires very little advanced mathematics.